# Migration from Oracle to MySql

Tags: mysql, oracle, database-migration

I want to migrate from oracle to MySql. I am using MySql Migration tools 5.0.
Something went wrong in Migration wizard.

[image: Error while establishing connection]

Error message is

```
Connecting to source database and retrieve schemata names.
Initializing JDBC driver ... 
Driver class Oracle Thin JDBC Driver using Service
Opening connection ... 
Connection jdbc:oracle:thin:system/**********@//127.0.0.1:1521/OracleServiceXE
The list of schema names could not be retrieved (error: 0).
ReverseEngineeringOracle.getSchemata :Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
//127.0.0.1:1521/OracleServiceXE

Details: 
oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125)
oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:280)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:328)
oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:361)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:151)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:595)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
com.mysql.grt.modules.ReverseEngineeringGeneric.establishConnection(ReverseEngineeringGeneric.java:141)
com.mysql.grt.modules.ReverseEngineeringOracle.getSchemata(ReverseEngineeringOracle.java:43)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
com.mysql.grt.Grt.callModuleFunction(Unknown Source)
```

Both SQL servers are running on localhost.

How can I solve these errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the used service name to the oracle database, or modify the entered value 'OracleServiceXE' to the correct value 'XE'. The entered value looks a lot like the default windows service name and could be confused with the Oracle database service name.

To change the current instance service name to OracleServiceXE:

```
alter system set service_name = 'OracleServiceXE';
```

`lsnrctl services`

should also show the service name after wards, unless the database instance is in restricted state, in that case the connection using a service name will fail.

Comment: I oracle service name is already 'OracleServiceXE'

No need to change it.

Comment: @smitpatel24 you are correct, if lsnrctl show services does indeed show OracleServiceXE as a supported Oracle service. From what you wrote, the instance is in restricted session or does not support OracleServiceXE. So, what does lsnrctl show services show?

Comment: For XE, the database instance name is XE and that is the name of the service in TNSNAMES.ORA. That is what you need for JDBC. You don't use the Windows service name because (shock, horror) not everyone uses Windows.

Comment: @Gary Myers Yes In TNSNAMES.ORA service name is XE.
But windows services shows OracleServiceXE.

Comment: @smitpatel24 it is not the windows service name where you connect to, it is the Oracle service name, as listed in 'lsnrctl services' cmd.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your jdbc connection URL for Oracle is wrong. Typically it looks something like this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
```

What happens if you remove the double slashes `//` and replace the slash `/` between `1521/OracleServiceXE` by a colon `:` ?

Comment: MySql Migration tool sets the connection string.

And username pass is required because without it MySql can't select database(system schema) from which the data is to be fetched.

Comment: But you must have configured those values somewhere? What are the configured values?

Comment: Yes I have configured those vales in "source database connection" step in wizard. Those are "must" values. Without them wizard won't take any action.

Comment: In advanced option I tried what you suggested before.

It did't work.